# Почему способ форматирования, заключающийся в использовании % устарел?

Tags: python, python-3.9

я пишу проект для публикации на github и стараюсь учитывать все детали, способствующие лучшему восприятию моего кода. В моем коде используются SQL запросы в бд и соответственно я использую форматирование строк.

Я остановился на этом методе:

```py
async def insert(table_name: str, data: dict) -> str:
    columns, values = data.keys(), data.values()
    columns_list_length = len(columns)
    placeholders = [f'${i}' for i in range(columns_list_length)]

    query = 'insert into %s (%s) values (%s)' % \
            (
                table_name,
                params_separator.join(columns),
                params_separator.join(placeholders)
            )

    async with connection.transaction():
        return await connection.execute(query, values)
```

Его суть заключается в том, чтобы установить значения ключей словаря в качестве колонок, а их значения в качестве значений колонок. Я считаю, что способ форматирования %s выглядит приятнее, если использовать f-строки, то это начинает выглядеть ужасно в связи с тем, что внутри строки появляется неизмеримое количество скобок, с методом format все обстоит так же.
Есть ли какая-то причина, помимо слова "устаревший", способная лучше дать понять почему не стоит использовать %?

Comment: он не устарел, используйте тот способ, который для вас выглядит более предпочтительный, все способы форматирования равноправны

Comment: спасибо, я про этот способ форматирования читал и нашел вопрос на англоязычном стеке, в котором отвечающие рекомендовали воспользоваться методом format из-за того, что % устарел. Теперь буду знать)

Comment: в документации и в англоязычной литературе про этот метод пишут как "Old Style", но это просто потому что он "old" по сравнению с более новыми, появившимися позже. Сам же этот метод форматирования поддерживается самой последней версией python и полностью равноправен с другими способами, никаких ограничений по его использованию нет

Comment: я где-то  видел, что он уступает "новым" по скорости.

Comment: вообще у вас тут потенциальная sql-инъекция. нельзя значения подставлять в текст запроса. Еще я не понимаю как вы текстовые значения вообще записываете в БД. Что за библиотеку вы используете для работы с БД, в ней нет плейсхолдеров для корректной передачи значений ? (например как %s в psycopg2 или $N в asyncpg)

Comment: @Mike я понял о чем Вы. Я поменял код в вопросе. Так лучше?

Comment: Да, явно лучше. А остальное это все же дело вкуса. Я бы может вообще все в одну f-строку написал, но читабельность конечно была бы так себе. Или части insert собирал join (что я в принципе и делаю в похожей функции, но у меня insert поддерживает не только подстановку параметров, но и on conflict do nothing / update и returning, так что там сборка запроса несколько сложнее

Comment: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/   там вроде всё объяснено